# Do I need to set assignTimestampsAndWatermarks if I set my time characteristic to IngestionTime in Flink 1.10?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Do I need to set assignTimestampsAndWatermarks if I set my time characteristic to IngestionTime?

say I set my time characteristic of stream execution environment to Ingestion time as follows

`streamExecutionEnvironment.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.IngestionTime);`

do I need to call `datastream.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(AscendingTimestampExtractor)` ?

I thought `datastream.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks` is mandatory only if time characteristic is event time. No? If not, I am wondering how can I set `AscendingTimestampExtractor` in a distributed environment? is there any way to add monotonically increasing long(AscendingTimestampExtractor) without any distributed locks?

Comment: Did something make you think this has changed in Flink 1.10? If something has been poorly communicated, it would be good to fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no need to call `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks` when using ingestion time. With ingestion time, Flink assigns timestamps and watermarks automatically.

Also, there is never any need to worry about distributed locking when doing watermarking. Each local instance assigns watermarks locally, based on its knowledge of the local streams. For an `AscendingTimestampExtractor` it's enough that the timestamps are monotonically increasing in each instance.